# Spray foam on roof and HVAC

Tags: roof, roofing, spray-foam

I am re-foaming my flat roof (residential home). Typical process is to remove existing foam, then spray on ~1" of new foam, and after that, apply two coats of elastomeric which protects the foam from the sun. Question is about the HVAC units that are on the roof. The HVAC units are sitting on 4x4 posts, which sit on top of the foam.

A couple bids are requiring a crane to lift the units so they can completely remove old foam and put new foam in its place. A couple other bids are going to remove old foam around the perimeter of the HVAC/posts, spray new foam around it, then spray a layer of foam on top of the old foam that is underneath the HVAC that ties into the rest of the new foam.

I'm curious about the latter options where they keep the HVACs in place and remove the foam around the permiter and spray a layer on top of the old foam underneath the unit.

Is this an accepted way to do it? What would be any cons of doing it this way?  I know a pro is that it's cheaper as you don't have to pay for a crane.

Comment: I'm not clear on the roofing material we're talking about here. Foam is insulation. What's on top of that? Also, how big are these units that a crane is required? Is this a home?

Comment: @isherwood, Polyurethane foam is what they spray on top of flat roofs.  On top of that is typically elastomeric to protect the foam against the elements.

Comment: @Greg, what part of the world is this in?  I don't know a lot about flat roofs, but I haven't heard of putting foam on one.

Comment: @JPhi1618, I am in Arizona! Do an internet search for "foam roof az" and you will find a lot of phoenix companies offering the service.  Not everyone has foam roof for insulation, but since I do, it was installed improperly , and not maintained, thus future maintenance is impossible, thus going to replace it.

Comment: @Greg thanks, I guess it could be a regional or climate specific roof.  I’ll take a look.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on how the roofing material is reinstalled with plan B.

Comment: Are you saying that currently the AC units are sitting on top of the existing foam? Or do the 4x4's penetrate the existing foam and rest on the roof structure?

Comment: I'm unclear on why you would remove the foam in place, rather than just add a new layer and seal over the top...on the whole roof.

Comment: I'm with Ecnerwal.  Seems like a lot of work to remove the existing foam.  BTW, we're faced with a similar situation with the flat portions of our church roof.  We're just having a new 1/32" (?) elastomeric  membrane put down.  They're just going to gently raise the two roof mounted HVAC units a bit so that the membrane can be slid under them.  So no need for a crane.

Comment: @ecnereal- I'm familiar with the foam system in use here. The new layer needs a rigid surface to bond to. The failed layer can be unstable, which leads to failure of the new layer. There might also be trapped moisture, which needs to be exposed and dried. If the original layer didn't bond properly, then moisture can run under the foam quite a distance with no external indication.

Comment: maybe ask them how much extra to replace the AC  unit supports with something that reaches down to the solid part of the roof and can be foamed around. this might need to be done by AC fitters.

Comment: You indicate that the original install wasn't done properly, thus making maintenance more difficult. If renting the crane allows for a proper installation and the no-crane is improper (I have no idea, this is all new to me), it seems like it would be worth the one-time financial hit to ensure it's maintainable in the future. If both allow for proper installation, then, well, it sounds like it's just a financial decision. I can't imagine that the "rent a crane" guys get much business if both methods work equally well.

Comment: @longneck, the two 4x4 posts lay flat on top of the roof, and then then HVAC rests on top of it.  That is common in this area for residential on a flat roof.  And yes, if the original foam was installed incorrectly, not only can you get large bubbles in areas, but it can lead to rot in the wood underneath it.  I got a hold of a someone in the hvac wholesale business - they said they've seen it both ways, and if done properly, the foam around the 4x4 is good to go.

Comment: @Greg - that's the same way the condenser units sit on our church roof - just resting on 4x4's.